# Compare two objects by their field's field

Tags: java, sorting, java-8, comparator

I have a class named House and it has property of type `Room`.

```
class House {
   private Room room;
   // getters & setters
}
```

`Room` class has a property `roomCapacity`:

```
class Room {
   private int roomCapacity;
   // getters & setters
}
```

I want to sort House HashMap on the base of Room class property named roomCapacity.

```
Comparator<House> sortByRoomCapacity =
      Comparator.nullsFirst(Comparator.comparing(House::getRoom,
                   Comparator.nullsFirst(Comparator.naturalOrder())));
```

But for now I am inaccessible to get this property(getRoomCapacity) of Room class **House::getRoom**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're almost there.

One more nested `comparing` method should do the trick:

```
Comparator<House> sortByRoomCapacity =
         nullsFirst(comparing(House::getRoom, 
                              comparing(Room::getRoomCapacity, 
                                        nullsFirst(naturalOrder()))));
```